# admob ads are not shown with pro guard

Tags: android, admob, proguard

I developed android app and I used admob sdk 6.2.1 for showing ads, and when I tested the app on my real device and on the emulator,ads are shown.
but when I apply pro guard to my app and test it on my device(I tested it on another devices also) ads are not shown up, any help please!

Comment: whether you have checked it using apk or directly Run the application to mobile ???

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add this to your proguard:

```
-keep class com.google.ads.** # Don't proguard AdMob classes
-dontwarn com.google.ads.** # Temporary workaround for v6.2.1. It gives a warning that you can ignore
```

EDIT 2020:

For some time now, the Google Mobile Ads SDK has distributed its own proguard rules that get manifest merged into your app, so you don't need to add anything yourselves. The merged rules also keep around methods from third-party mediation adapters that are needed to make mediation work.

Comment: this answer is right, but we have to write these two lines in proguard-project.txt

Comment: @EricLeichtenschlag what does the last two asterisks do? Is it import all? What if it ends with `ads**` without the dot? Also, what does `{*;}` do too?

Comment: @Mr.Nacho - The `*` and `**` are wildcards - `*` is any number of characters not including package separators (`.`), and `**` is for any number of characters period.

Answer (score 11):

[From the docs](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/android/faq):

> To safely use ProGuard with Google Mobile Ads, add the following to your ProGuard config:

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.** {
    public *;
}

-keep public class com.google.ads.** {
    public *;
}
```

> This will prevent all public methods on public classes from being obfuscated.
>
> If you use AdMob Mediation with other ad networks, you should keep public methods from public classes for each SDK and adapter library as well.

Answer (score 1):

**Proguard Rules for Admob in Android**

```
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.ads.**{
   public *;
}

# For old ads classes
-keep public class com.google.ads.**{
   public *;
}

# For mediation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Other required classes for Google Play Services
# Read more at http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
   protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
   public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
   @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}

-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
   public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```

Comment: I wrote title Admob Proguard Rules it's obvious you need to add this code in proguard rules file.

Comment: It takes a lot of time to understand and make it work. In flutter, there is no proguard-rules.pro file by default. My ads are not showing because Admob needs unique traffic at the start to make sure ads show to the right users, not to the developer. Test ads in release mode are showing, so that means there is no need for a proguard-rules.pro file.

Comment: Ok i will update my answer this is only for android and it's work better with earlier version of admob library.