# New Admob, Proguard, and Android 2.3

Tags: android, admob, proguard

I'm integrating the new AdMob into my apps. The documentation states API 9 or above is required. Now here's the problem:

In debug mode, AdMob works fine on any supported devices. When I apply Proguard, devices running API-9 stop showing the ads, whereas more recent APIs still show the ads correctly. On API-9, the following shows up in Logcat:

```
11-08 00:32:03.523: W/Ads(24719): Could not get info for ad overlay.
```

Given that the problem only appears after Proguard, I assume this is due to a support class that is getting obfuscated. Unfortunately, AdMob's integration guide includes no instructions for Proguard, and my searching efforts have only yielded some suggestions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344305/admob-ads-are-not-shown-with-pro-guard) which haven't fixed the issue. Currently, my Proguard config is as follows:

```
-keep class com.google.ads.**
-dontwarn com.google.ads.**
-keep class com.google.android.gms.ads.**
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.ads.**
-keep public class com.google.gson.**
```

Anything else I need to add to it to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I am not to sure but try this:

```
-keep public class com.google.gson.**
```