# Real ads not showing in release mode although the proguard is deactive. What may be the problem?

Tags: android, admob, proguard

I registered to admob about 24 hours ago. Confirmation mail come from admob. I added admob id's to my app. When i install my app to a real device by clicking run button in android studio, the real ads showing properly. So my admob ids work correctly.

However, when i generate signed apk and install the apk to my device by apk install ... command using Android Studio terminal, real ads does not showing. I firstly think that the problem is related to proguard however it is not related to proguard. Because i deactivated proguard and the real ads still not showing. What may be the problem?

build.gradle (app level):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.bugsnag.android.gradle'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "...."
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.4'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.nex3z:flow-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.1'
    implementation 'com.bugsnag:bugsnag-android:4.+'
}
```

build.gradle(project level)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
        classpath 'com.bugsnag:bugsnag-android-gradle-plugin:3.+'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Did you check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13344305/admob-ads-are-not-shown-with-pro-guard) ?

Comment: @Benoit , yes i read that question and write that codes into proguard file and tested not work. Then i totally deactivated the progueard and release my app. Now no ads are shown in my app.

Comment: @metis Do have enable your billing details?

Comment: Do any(even test) ads show up? Or no ads are shown up?

Comment: @metis Can you please also post the layout and activity code?

Comment: any error code return in adlistner ?

Comment: are you try run in real device?

Comment: yes tried on real device and not work. After one week later, the problem is solved with no change. I think google has banned my apps ads for one week because i tested real ads for more than 100 times

Answer (score 0):

Check your `logcat`, if you are getting `W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 3` warning it means that the ad request was successful, but no ad was returned due to lack of ad inventory so your code is OK! You just need to wait a couple of days and the ads will appear.

I had a similar issue with my app, I published it as beta on `Google Play` on `5 dec` then the full release on `19 dec` and ads started to show only today!

Comment: I am suffering by the same issue from start of app release. I am getting 15% match rate. Even I found no reason for low match rate, we can only wait.