# pro-guard configuration error while generating APK

Tags: android, apk, proguard, obfuscation, android-proguard

Getting this error while applying pro-guard

```
Unexpected error while performing partial evaluation:
  Class       = [com/google/android/gms/ads/AdLoader$Builder]
  Method      = [forPublisherAdView(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/formats/OnPublisherAdViewLoadedListener;[Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdSize;)Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdLoader$Builder;]
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of [com/google/android/gms/internal/zzko] (with 1 known super classes) and [android/os/RemoteException] (with 5 known super classes))
Unexpected error while preverifying:
  Class       = [com/google/android/gms/ads/AdLoader$Builder]
  Method      = [forPublisherAdView(Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/formats/OnPublisherAdViewLoadedListener;[Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdSize;)Lcom/google/android/gms/ads/AdLoader$Builder;]
  Exception   = [java.lang.IllegalArgumentException] (Can't find common super class of [com/google/android/gms/internal/zzko] (with 1 known super classes) and [android/os/RemoteException] (with 5 known super classes))
```

While generating signed apk. I have checked some of questions and answers but it doest help.

**proguard-rules.pro**

```
-ignorewarnings

-keep class * {
    public private *;
}

-keep class com.google.android.gms.internal.** { *; }
-keep public class com.google.android.gms.* { public *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
-keep class com.facebook.ads.** { *; }
```

Comment: Add rules with question which you using for Admod SDK . Also dependency version of library .

Comment: @ADM updated my question. Please check.

Comment: Try Adding [Rules](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20576654/4168607).

Comment: @ADM same error after adding rules in that answer.

Comment: for test case comment `-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.internal.zzko`

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya even after removal it is same. i can share code if needed

Comment: i have updated code. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution.

After applying pro-guard, it was not showing me exact error but after more efforts it shows actual error and if remove pro-guard than there was no error.

This error was due to **some missing resources** as during build it is taking from cache i guess.

Answer (score 0):

A configuration rule with `includedescriptorclasses` should keep it:

```
-keep,includedescriptorclasses class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-keep,includedescriptorclasses class com.google.android.gms.internal.** { *; }
-keep,includedescriptorclasses class com.google.android.gms.ads.** { *; }
```

While keeping `private` methods defeats the idea of obfuscation:

```
-keep class * {public private *;}
```

Comment: @AmitVaghela I've changed the namespace, to match the class in question.

Comment: i have just added **-ignorewarnings

-keep,includedescriptorclasses class com.google.ads.** { *; }**

Comment: after updating i am getting **Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can't find common super class of [com/google/android/gms/internal/zzko] (with 1 known super classes) and [android/os/RemoteException] (with 5 known super classes)**